# Gallery CSS into JQuery / Ajax page div

Tags: jquery, ajax, stylesheet, gallery

Please someone help me out with this:

I have the gallery html page loaded and getting called in correctly to my mainContent div in my page.  if you go here:

http://dageniusmarketer.com/DigitalWonderland/index-jquery.html

click on portfolio, you will see that the gallery loads, but, the image thumbnails and display is way off. its supposed to look and act like this:

dageniusmarketer.com/DigitalWonderland/pages/Galleriffic/advanced.html

I believe it has everything to do with loading the stylesheet for the gallery into my mainContent div, only that I do not know how to do it.  I may be wrong, but i believe that is the problem.  Could someone view my source and tell me how to fix it so the gallery displays the correct way in my main site?

I also would like to load the home page into the mainContent div upon initial loading of the site.  How do I do this?

Any and all help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you load the page "Portfolio" into your mainpage (index-jquery.html), the paths to the css and javascript in the loaded html are wrong. They point to non-existend locations.

When I adjusted the paths to `<link type="text/css" href="http://dageniusmarketer.com/DigitalWonderland/pages/Galleriffic/css/basic.css" rel="stylesheet"/>` and like wise for the other `<link>` and `<script>` tags in the embedded page, it was properly displayed.

I recommend using a tool like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) for Mozilla Firefox, which allowed me to see the DOM and modify it to help me debug your code.